# Chain rule while differentiating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the derivative of a function defined in polar coordinates with respect to $x$ and $y$. My function is defined as follows:

$ v_x(r, \theta ) = v_r \cos (\theta ) - v_{\theta }\sin (\theta ) $

To do this, I start by defining the relation between Cartesian and Polar coordinates:

```
(* Define the mapping between Cartesian and Polar coordinate systems. *)
x[r_, θ_] = r Cos[θ];
y[r_, θ_] = r Sin[θ];
```

Then I define the function and find its derivative with respect to $x$:

```
Subscript[v, r][r_, θ_] = Subscript[v, r][r, θ] Cos[θ] - Subscript[v, θ][r, θ] Sin[θ];
D[Subscript[v, r][r, θ], x]
```

I am getting 0 because *Mathematica* is not considering the relation between $r$ and $x$. Is there anyway to tell *Mathematica* to use the chain rule to find the derivative of $v_x$ with respect to $x$?

The other problem is that *Mathematica* is considering the subscripts to be variables (which is reasonable), is there anyway to tell it that the subscripts are only notational symbols?

**EDIT**: The function is better defined as:

```
vx[r_, θ_] = vr[r, θ] Cos[θ] - vtheta[r, θ] Sin[θ];
```

to avoid evaluating subscripts and possibly having recursion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case it might be more convenient to define the inverse transformation :

```
rho[x_, y_] = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
theta[x_, y_] = ArcTan[x, y]

 vx[r_, \[Theta]_] = vr[r, \[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]] - vtheta[r, \[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]];
```

Then this will use the chain rule :

```
 D[vx[rho[x, y], theta[x, y]], x]
```

One can simplify the result in terms of the polar coordinated :

```
Simplify[D[vx[rho[x, y], theta[x, y]], x] /. {x^2 + y^2 -> rho^2, ArcTan[x, y] -> theta, x -> rho Cos[theta], y -> rho Sin[theta]}, Assumptions -> {rho >= 0}]
```

Comment: This works but it produces everything in terms of x and y, which is very complicated!

Comment: well if it works you could always upvote it to indicate that you appreciate his effort :)

Comment: @Rafid Please see edit for some additional simplification.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, for total conversion back to polar coordinates you will need to add `x -> rho Cos[theta], y -> rho Sin[theta]` to the replacement rules.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. How about the second question?

Comment: @Rafid Please have a look at the [Notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) package.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the total derivative [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dt.html):

```
x[r_, \[Theta]_] = r Cos[\[Theta]];
y[r_, \[Theta]_] = r Sin[\[Theta]];
```

then for instance

```
Dt[a[r, \[Theta]]*Cos[\[Theta]] - b[r, \[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]], x]
```

does this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can't test your example because `Subscript[v, r][r_, \[Theta]_] = 
 Subscript[v, r][r, \[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]] - 
  Subscript[v, \[Theta]][r, \[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]` hits the recursion limit (because the way it's defined and the evaluation sequence works, it'll never finish). However, here's how to indicate that something is a constant. Suppose I try:

```
Dt[Sin[\[Theta]] + c, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but $c$ is a constant; I can indicate this like so:

```
Dt[Sin[\[Theta]] + c, x, Constants -> {c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not substituting the values and dr/dx and dtheta/dx, so it is not really making use of the Cartesian-Polar equations!

Comment: @Rafid Right. So you expect to define `x[r,Theta]:=etc` and have Mathematica automatically insert the values for $\partial_x\theta$ etc? That's not going to be 2 lines of code. By the way, did you notice that the code in your question goes into infinite recursion?

Comment: Well, honestly, I am relatively new to Mathematica, so I thought this might be possible since I am already passing in the relation. Anyway, thanks, one vote :-) And yes, I did notice the recursion, I am going to edit my question now.