# How to define a rule to simplify the notation for derivatives of chain rule?

Tags: replacement

Suppose that $u(x,y)$ is a function, and $x=r \cos t$, $y= r \sin t$, then we can define a new function $v(r,t):=u(x,y)$ with $x,y$ replaced by the above equations. It is quite easy to compute $v$'s derivatives, for example $\partial_{rr}v(r,t)$ can be computed in MMA as

```
v[r_, t_] := u[x, y] /. {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]}

D[v[r, t], {r, 2}] // Simplify
```

The output of which looks like

[image]

Then, my question is how to define a new rule, to make the output above look like:
$$
\sin^2tu_{tt}+\sin(2t)u_{rt}+\cos^2tu_{rr}.
$$

Comment: Related: [Chain rule while differentiating](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9086/4330) and [How to make traditional output for derivatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23659/4330)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
Simplify[D[v[r, t], {r, 2}]] /. {Derivative[0, 2][u_][__] :> 
   Subscript[u, tt], Derivative[1, 1][u_][__] :> Subscript[u, rt], 
  Derivative[2, 0][u_][__] :> Subscript[u, rr]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to that of RunnyKine. The notation is a little bit different, which could be convenient if we want to differentiate more than two times.

Note that the OPs definition can probably for `v` can also be written as follows. The order of evaluation is a bit different, but the definition should otherwise be equivalent.

```
v[r_, t_] := u[r Cos[t], r Sin[t]];
```

I have made two rules, which I suppose could be merged into one. But it is nice to think about them this way. The rule `rule` below can change expressions containing `Derivative` (as the "highest head"), which is displayed like a superscript, into an expression with a subscript. I simply copy the the numbers which appear in the superscript notation and put them in the subscript notation, and in the subscript notation I add the names of the variables, `r` and `t`. The wrapper `HoldForm` is an unimportant detail.

```
rule =
 Derivative[a_, b_][u][r Cos[t], r Sin[t]] :> 
  Subscript[u, a HoldForm@r, b HoldForm@t ];
```

One thing is a bit tricky here, as perhaps some unexpected evaluation will occur. `Subscript` has no attribute like `Hold` or `HoldAll`, so its arguments will be evaluated, as usual. As a result `1*HoldForm[r]` will evaluate to `HoldForm[r]` and `0*HoldForm[r]` will evaluate to `0`.

I like the way it looks, except that when we differentiate to some variable 0 times, I would rather not write anything than write 0. So I delete the 0's.

```
rule2 =
 sub_Subscript :>
  DeleteCases[sub, 0, Infinity]
```

Then

```
D[v[r, t], {r, 2}] /. rule /. rule2 // Simplify
```

gives you

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Need some explain of your code, I don't understand.

Comment: @vanabel I think it is pretty similar to RunnyKine's code. I will add a little explanation :)

Comment: yes, I see. But I prefer Runykine's simple and work almost the same as I expected. Thanks for your code all the same.